# start_created_at not working with /collectors/{id}/responses

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm using this Google app script to query Survey Monkey results:

```
function surveyMonkey() {
  var token = "xxx";
  var survey = "xxx";
  var options = {"headers": {"authorization": "bearer "+token}};
  var api_key = "xxx";
  var url = 'https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/';
  var responseURL = 'collectors/xxx/responses?api_key='+api_key
  +'&sort_by=date_modified&sort_order=DESC'
  +'&start_modified_at=2016-04-01T00:00:00+00:00'
  var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+responseURL, options);
  var responseData = JSON.parse(responses.getContentText());
  Logger.log(responseData);
}
```

I'm trying to call the response collector "/collectors/{id}/responses". When I exclude the query string for start_modified_at, I will get a valid JSON response. When I try to include start_modified_at, I will not get a response.

I've also tried this with just "/surveys/{id}/responses" and I'm getting the same results. It works without the date and does not work when a date is included. I've removed my own info and replaced it with xxx to share the code.

The goal is to only return responses from yesterday and append it to a spreadsheet.

This also happens with any query string that includes a date string. Are there any ideas what I might be doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that the `+` is being replaced with a space by the time it gets to our end. So it fails validation. You need to encode the URL parameters before sending them to us. So in this case the "+" will be "%2B".

Apparently Google app script is like javascript and you can solve it with `encodeURIComponent('start_modified_at=2016-04-01T00:00:00+00:00')`.

We definitely need to work on getting you back better error messages for invalid URL parameters! Try that and let us know if you still hit issues.

Comment: The url being sent on my end in the debugger looks like [link](https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors/xxx/responses?api_key=xxx&sort_by=date_modified&sort_order=DESC&start_modified_at=2016-04-01T12:56:55+00:00)

Comment: And this is the full Error Response I'm getting when I hard code the entire url: 

Request failed for https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/xxx/responses/bulk?api_key=xxx&sort_by=date_modified&sort_order=DESC&per_page=10&start_modified_at=2016-04-01T12:56:55+00:00 returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error": {"docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes", "message": "Invalid URL parameters.", "id": "1003", "name": "Bad Reque... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 19, file "surveyMonkey")

Comment: Yes so in this case the date modified should be `start_modified_at=2016-04-01T12%3A56%3A55%2B00%3A00`