# Survey Monkey API: /collectors/{id}/responses/bulk?start_created_at= Returns a Bad Request Error

Tags: uri, query-string, surveymonkey

I'm using python 3.6.4. Trying to retrieve data from Survey Monkey API using the following:

```
access_token = 'xxx'
collector_id = 'yyy'

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({
                  "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % access_token,
                  "Content-Type": "application/json"
                })
url = "https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/collectors/%s/responses/bulk?start_created_at=2020- 
02-11T23:20:00+00:00" % (collector_id) 
res = s.get(url)
dat = res.json()
```

Unfortunately this leads to the following error:

```
{'error': {'id': '1003',
'name': 'Bad Request',
'docs': 'https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes',
'message': 'Invalid URL parameters.',
'http_status_code': 400}}
```

I found a post that addresses the same issue as here but the solutions provided there didn't work for me. Here is the post: 
[start_created_at not working with /collectors/{id}/responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433093/start-created-at-not-working-with-collectors-id-responses)

Can someone point me in the right direction regarding how I can format the query string so that my URL parameter I'd like to filter by is valid?

Comment: You probably need to escape the `+` and perhaps the colons. You say the referenced solution did not work for you. How did you try to implement it?

Comment: I url encoded the date string using urllib.parse.quote('2020-02-11T23:20:00+00:00'). So then my url looked like "https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/collectors/%s/responses/bulk?state_created_at=2020-02-11T23%3A20%3A00%2B00%3A00" instead. That gave me a different error, namely TypeError: not enough arguments for format string. Sorry, http protocol is very new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode only the date/time portion of the URL. Try this:

```
timedate = '2020-02-11T23:20:00+00:00'
timedate_enc = urllib.parse.quote(timedate)
url = 'https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/collectors/%s/responses/bulk?start_created_at=%s' % (collector_id, timedate_enc)
```

Comment: The encoding was changing the initial colon which is not valid. I updated my answer to encode only the time and date.